# hibernate - using 'having' without group by clause in hql

Tags: oracle, hibernate

im trying to run an hql query which aggragets (sum) number of transactions made on a specific account, i dont need a group by since my where clause has a specific account filter (where account = :account)

i do, however, want to return the aggregated value only if it is smaller/bigger than some given value.
when im adding 'having' after the where clause without 'group by' im getting an error - 
unexpected token: having

in native sql i succeeded adding 'having' without group by

any ideas on how to make it work with hql?

thanks alot

Comment: And the reason you don't want to group is, that you want to return other non-groupable columns, too? How should the server know, which row's column to return? Picking one randomly?

Comment: having without group by is really vague,

Comment: i need to return only one column, the aggregated one so there should be no problem for the server to figure out what to return
i'm using oracle

Answer (score 0):

The reason why databases don't let you mix grouped columns with non-grouped and non-aggregated ones is, that for non-grouped/non-aggregated columns it would have to choose one row's value per group, but doesn't know how to pick one.

If you don't care, then you could just leave it away and if it doesn't matter because they're all the same, you could group by them, too.

Comment: not sure i follow.
im returning just one column, the aggregated one

Comment: Long story short: You can't have HAVING without GROUP BY. This only works with questionable databases. Why don't you want to group, anyway?

Comment: i just want to sum a column (lets say transactions) for a specific account id. so if in my where clause im writing where account =: account, i have no use of grouping by anything
i also want to return 0 when the account id is not on my table (so im using right join on the account table an use coalesce)


thanks for your reply

Comment: I still don't see, why you insist on doing it without grouping. That's the way it works.

Comment: So then just use where.  This is the way is works.  where defines predicates applied *before* the grouping; having defines predicates applied *after* the grouping.  Here, it sounds like you just want where.

Answer (score 0):

It is not hql, but if you have native query, then run it like:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select, *** ,... blah blah")
//set If you need
query.setParameter("myparam", "val"); 
List result = query.list();
```

Answer (score -1):

In my eyes this is nonsense. 'having' is done for conditions on a 'group by' result. If you don't group, then it does not make much sense.

I would say HQL can't do it. Probably the Hibernate programmers didn't think of this case because they considered it as not important.

And anyway, you don't need it.

If it is a simple query, then you can decide in your java code if you want the result or if you don't need it.

If it is in a subselect, then you can solve the problem with a where condition in the main select.

If you think it is really necessary then your invited to give a more concrete example.

Comment: i guess its not that important, just wanted to know if it could be done. im running an hql with respect to another object so some time im using group by and sometime not. so, if not using having when there is no group by, i will have to check the value in my java code and when i will use group by ill have to add some logic to my java code not to check the returned value.
not a big deal but thought i could avoid it